# Google Cloud mainPageSuffix not working for bucket under CDN

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, bucket

I have the following config:

Bucket name: `subdomain.example.com`

KeyCDN which has origin to `http://subdomain.example.com` and which gives me a new URL `random-123.kxcdn.com`

I have my domain `example.com` which has a `CNAME`: Host `@`, value: `random-123.kxcdn.com`

When I go to `example.com` I see the default XML response with bucket's files. If I go to `example.com/index.html` I see the correct website.

If I run:

`gsutil web get gs://subdomain.example.com`

I get:

`{"mainPageSuffix": "index.html", "notFoundPage": "404.html"}`

So basically, with this "CNAME to CDN to bucket" configuration, the rule to serve `index.html` by default is not working

Answer (score 4):

Please review the steps proposed inside this [page](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/web).

> I have my domain example.com which has a CNAME: Host @, value:
>   random-123.kxcdn.com

If you look inside the link, you'll see that you should add a DNS CNAME record for *www.example.com* pointing to *c.storage.googleapis.com* - I think this might be your error.

Also I don't see you citing this step, please ensure you have run gsutil web set:

```
gsutil web set -m index.html -e 404.html gs://www.example.com
```

Also remember that changes to the DNS records are not immediate, wait for a while for the propagation to happen :)

Comment: I added the output of `gsutil web get ...` to make it clear that I configred everything correctly. Also, I need to point the root domain, not a subdomain.